# I have a stored procedure that is getting the warning "1287 Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated"

Tags: mysql

I have a stored procedure that is getting the "Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'." warning in MySQL 8.0.28.

It is all working fine as it should apart from the warning

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `po_sp_update_category`//
CREATE PROCEDURE `po_sp_update_category`(
  IN    p_ID            INT,
  IN    p_Category_Group_ID INT,
  IN    p_Name          VARCHAR(50),
  IN    p_Sort_Order        INT,
  IN    p_Description       TEXT,
  IN    p_Picture       INT
)
BEGIN

  DECLARE   v_RecordsUpdated    INT;
  DECLARE   v_ID            INT;
  DECLARE   v_DuplicateCategory INT;

  SELECT  COUNT(ID)
  INTO    v_DuplicateCategory
  FROM    po_tblcategory
  WHERE   Name          =   p_Name
  AND     ID            <>  p_ID
  ;

  IF v_DuplicateCategory > 0 THEN

    SELECT  2105        AS  DB_ERROR,
            p_ID        AS  DB_ID
    FROM    DUAL
    ;

  ELSE

    IF p_ID = -1 THEN
    
      INSERT INTO po_tblcategory
        (
    ID,
    Category_Group_ID,
    Name,
    Sort_Order,
    Description,
    Picture
    )
      VALUES
    (
    NULL,
    p_Name,
    p_Category_Group_ID,
    p_Sort_Order,
    p_Description,
    p_Picture
    )
    ;
        
    SELECT  ROW_COUNT()
    INTO    v_RecordsUpdated
    ;
        
    SELECT  LAST_INSERT_ID()
    INTO    v_ID
    ;
    
    IF v_RecordsUpdated > 0 THEN
                 
        SELECT  100     AS  DB_ERROR,
            v_ID        AS  DB_ID
        FROM    DUAL
        ;
                
    ELSE
                        
        SELECT  2107        AS  DB_ERROR,
            v_ID        AS  DB_ID
        FROM    DUAL
        ;
            
    END IF;
    ELSE
    
    UPDATE  po_tblcategory
    SET Name            =   p_Name,
        Category_Group_ID   =   p_Category_Group_ID,
        Sort_Order      =   p_Sort_Order,
        Description     =   p_Description,
        Picture         =   p_Picture
    WHERE   ID          =   p_ID
    ;
        
    SELECT  100         AS  DB_ERROR,
        p_ID            AS  DB_ID
    FROM    DUAL
    ;
        
    END IF;
        
    SET @ordering_inc = 10;
    SET @new_ordering = 0;

    UPDATE  po_tblcategory  
    SET     Sort_Order      =   (@new_ordering := @new_ordering + @ordering_inc)
    ORDER BY    Sort_Order      ASC,
        Name            ASC
    ;       


  END IF;
END
```

The problem is that I think I am already doing the required solution (But obviously I am not....) I am using SELECT INTO to put the value into the local variable as they suggest. Also I have declared the variable at the top of the procedure along with the Type.
I am, not sure what else I can do!

What am I missing?

Comment: *What am I missing?* The problem is the next code fragment: `.. (@new_ordering := @new_ordering + @ordering_inc) ..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your last statements (two SETs and UPDATE) with

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Sort_Order ASC, Name ASC) AS rn
    FROM po_tblcategory
    )
UPDATE po_tblcategory t1
  JOIN cte t2 USING (id)
SET t1.Sort_Order = (t2.rn - 1) * 10;
```

where `id` is primary key expression.

Comment: Hey, that's it.  Did not know about the ROW_NUMBER function.  I'm sure that could come in handy

Comment: @KyleWhite https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html - study carefully.